# How do i change values in windows 8 registry editor without it returning to the default?

Tags: windows-8, display, windows-registry, fonts, dpi

I tried to reduce my windows 8 display scaling with the registry editor, but when i restart or sign out, it returns to the original value.[this image should explain better](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O4lVS.png)

Answer (score 0):

You could change the permissions of the key in Regedit **but this might prevent the key from working, so back up the key before attempting this.**

- Right-click and select *Permissions...*
- Click the *Advanced* button.
- If you're not the owner, click *Change* and take ownership.
- Click *Disable inheritance* button.

[image: Disable inheritance warning]

Continue through the dialogs, and the Registry object will be *fairly well* protected... though it is possible a system process could change the value, despite these restrictions.

Comment: It didn't work. It still returns to the original value after i restart.